# VBA: Get attribute names from xml

Tags: excel, vba

How to get all attribute names from below xml in vba, I`m trying to collect attribute names dynamically instead of hard coding in excel, attribute names may increase or decrease.

```
<Doc a="1" b="2">
    <Doc1 aa="1" bb="2" cc="3" dd="4"/>
    <Doc1 aa="1" bb="2" cc="3" dd="4" ee="5"/>
    <Doc1 aa="1" bb="2" cc="3" dd="4"/>
    <Doc1 aa="1" bb="2" cc="3" dd="4" ff="6"/>
    <Doc1 aa="1" bb="2" cc="3" dd="4" gg="7"/>
</Doc>
```

Please suggest me a way.

Comment: have you tried any ways of solving this yourself and if so could you please post them?

Comment: or [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q)

Answer (score 0):

XML is always a challenge.... Your reading code is highly dependent on the writing code and the hope that it never changes. Your source is one of the stranger ones.

I always have to go searching around the net to find solutions to problems like these and usually the posts do not line up with the version of XML tool I have at hand. Usually you can use your IDE to look at the object library and find corresponding properties and methods to those you find in posts. In Excel F2 brings up the object browser and you can look at the MSXML2 library.

```
            Sub test()
                ' add reference to MSXML v6
                'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx
                'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/bb190600.aspx
                Dim xdoc As New DOMDocument60
                Dim s As String
                s = s & "<Doc a=""1"" b=""2"">"
                s = s & "<Doc1 aa=""1"" bb=""2"" cc=""3"" dd=""4""/>"
                s = s & "<Doc1 aa=""1"" bb=""2"" cc=""3"" dd=""4"" ee=""5""/>"
                s = s & "<Doc1 aa=""1"" bb=""2"" cc=""3"" dd=""4""/>"
                s = s & "<Doc1 aa=""1"" bb=""2"" cc=""3"" dd=""4"" ff=""6""/>"
                s = s & "<Doc1 aa=""1"" bb=""2"" cc=""3"" dd=""4"" gg=""7""/>"
                s = s & "</Doc>"
                xdoc.LoadXML (s)
                DisplayNodes2 xdoc
            End Sub

            Sub DisplayNodes2(xmlDoc As DOMDocument60)
                'http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/454fbc72-ab87-4479-b0bf-b7925834ac4e/
                Dim xelem As IXMLDOMElement
                Dim xa As IXMLDOMAttribute
                For Each xelem In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//*")
                    Debug.Print xelem.nodeName
                    For Each xa In xelem.Attributes
                        Debug.Print xa.Name, xa.Value
                    Next xa
                Next xelem
            End Sub
```